# npm package regex doesn't work with the simple regular expression ".*"

Tags: regex, node.js

I used the following code:

```
var Regex = require('regex');
var regex = new Regex(/.*/);
console.log(regex.test('abcde'));  // false
```

and I don't know why, but it returns false. The regexp ".*" is supposed to match any string. Why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: And with `var regex = /.*/;`?

Comment: mmm... it works :-). But why doesn't it work with new Regex(...)?

Comment: Do not use the regex literal inside a constructor. It is not widely supported as of now.

Comment: OK. But this is what the documentation of the 'regex' directory tells: https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex

Comment: Why use a constructor if you can pass a literal? But I agree there is something wrong: either with the docs, or with the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This module doesn't currently work for some patterns.

See [issue #4](https://github.com/aaditmshah/regex/issues/4) in the project's repo on GitHub.

I have just posted a [pull request #5](https://github.com/aaditmshah/regex/pull/5) that adds tests for those cases.

Also, the only commit in that repo since May 15, 2013 was [changing the email of the maintainer](https://github.com/aaditmshah/regex/commit/048ca4a0357192f4c6b8326589c913288f00b863#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2L6) so this module may be abandoned. You may want to contact the maintainer to get some more info on the status of this project.